Changing ListObject name based on cell value
I have a sheet witih multiple tables in it and need the tables to change their names based on cell values.  Please see below code and let me know what is making this not work, thanks!
Dim tblName As String

tblName = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value & " ClI"

With shtB
    .Range("S7").ListObject.Name = tblName
End With


What's the problem with the code?  Worked fine for me - it replaced the space with an underscore.  I was expecting it to throw an error on that, but just quietly did the replacement.

What does "not work" mean? You get an error? Nothing happens? Table gets a wrong name? A wrong table get the name?  Please check: Is shtB a valid object? Is the cell S7 part of a table? Is tblName a valid table name?

My apologies!  Dealing with jet lag, should have given more information.  Run Time error 91 - Object variable or with block variable not set.  Cell S7 is a cell part of the table, top left corner to be exact.  tblName is not currently a table name, its the variable I was hoping to have the table name change to.  I want the table name to change to what is in cell A1 & " CLI".  Table is in the same sheet as the Cell A1.

When you get 91, either ShtB is not set or cell S7 of sheet ShtB is not part of a ListObject. I would guess it's the first: Is ShtB a global var, is it a local var that you don't declare (and don't assign anything) or do you have a sheet with the codeName (not the sheet name) shtB? Are you using Option Explicit?

ShtB is the called variable for the activeSheet, I had ActiveSheet at first and got same error.  Then I changed the code to reference the variable I gave Activesheet for testing purposes.  Option explicit seems to break the entire sub in other ways.  I did find out just now this code does work if I have an entirely new module with the option explicit and I call that module at the end of the original sub
